# html form is not posting input control values on postback

Tags: html, forms, post

I have a very simple html page with one form and few controls in it. This html page is hosted on a server. When I post this form with some values in input fields it does not show input values in form post data.

reuest body only has btn1=post other controls are not listed there

below is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <form id="form4" action="somePage.htm" method="post" >
    <input type="text" id="textMain1" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="textMain2" value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="textMain3" value=""/>

    <input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>![enter image description here][2]
```

These things I have already tried:
-adding name and id attribute together to input control
-adding runat=server in case (html page is written in VS IDE)
-add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form 
-run it in chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

may be this [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is defined what you want and useful for you

```
$("#form4").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
 var values = $(this).serialize();

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "post",
  data: values,
  success: function(){

  },

  }); 
});
```

Comment: stange but a simple IISreset resolved the issue. Can't use Jquery as the client browser does not support it. Always have name attribute in controls which you intend to be there in post data.                      name1:2
name2:5
name3:6
btn1:post